# Setting up a Green's Theorem Problem where C is not oriented counterclockwise

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Use Green's Theorem to evaluate $\mathbf{F}(x,y)=\langle y^{2}\cos x, x^{2}+2y\sin x\rangle$, where $C$ is the triangle from $(0,0)$ to $(2,6)$ to $(2,0)$ to $(0,0)$.

Taking the appropriate partial derivatives, I have my integral set up as $\displaystyle \int_{C}y^{2}\cos x\, dx +(x^{2}+2y\sin x)\,dy = \displaystyle \int_{2}^{0}\int_{0}^{3x}2x\, dy\, dx$.  My reasoning for the order of the limits of integration was that since we are going from 2 to 0 along the bottom edge of the triangle, the $dx$ integral should have limits of integration from 2 to 0.

For the $dy$, integral, however, I'm not quite as sure.  In the y-direction, it seems as though we're going from 0 to $3x$, because of how the curve is oriented along the hypotenuse.

But, I'm second-guessing myself - I still don't feel like I have the hang of setting these problems up, so if you could 1) tell me whether I'm right, and 2) if I'm not right, explain to me why, so I don't make the same mistake again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the problem says youre going from 0,0 to 2,6 and 2,6 to 2,0 and back to 0,0 which in conclusion means youre traveling clockwise. Since greens theorem by default is defined positive counter clockwise whenever your traveling around the boundary clockwise just add a negative sign in the very front of the integral. Your limits of integration on y is correct from 0 to 3x. For the xlimits your going from a=0 to b=2. Remember that you need to put a negative sign because your traveling clockwise and because of this negative sign it allows you to swap the limits and go from a=2 to b=0 and make the negative sign dissappear. So your setup happens to be correct just because your traversing the curve clockwise. If it wasn't for that youll be off by a negative sign. The answer you should get after evaluating the double integral is -16. Best,